# How to build Timelock Dao with Access Control?

Tags: solidity, foundry, dao, timelock

```
import {TimelockController} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/TimelockController.sol";
contract DaoTimelockController is TimelockController {
    constructor(
        address _core,
        uint256 _minDelay
    )
        
        TimelockController(
            _minDelay,
            new address[](0), // Should this be 0? Or Governor instance?
            new address[](0),
            address(0)
        )
    {}
```

This is the Governor Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

import {Governor, IGovernor} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/Governor.sol";
import {GovernorSettings} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorSettings.sol";
import {GovernorTimelockControl} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControl.sol";
import {GovernorVotes, IERC165} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotes.sol";
import {GovernorCountingSimple} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimple.sol";
import {IVotes} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/utils/IVotes.sol";
import {TimelockController} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/TimelockController.sol";
import {CoreRef} from "@src/core/CoreRef.sol";
import {CoreRoles} from "@src/core/CoreRoles.sol";

/// @title Governor for on-chain governance of Ethereum Credit Guild, based on the OZ implementation.
/// @author eswak
contract GuildGovernor is
    CoreRef,
    Governor,
    GovernorVotes,
    GovernorTimelockControl,
    GovernorSettings,
    GovernorCountingSimple
{
    /// @notice Private storage variable for quorum (the minimum number of votes needed for a vote to pass).
    uint256 private _quorum;

    /// @notice Emitted when quorum is updated.
    event QuorumUpdated(uint256 oldQuorum, uint256 newQuorum);

    constructor(
        address _core,
        address _timelock,
        address _token,
        uint256 initialVotingDelay,
        uint256 initialVotingPeriod,
        uint256 initialProposalThreshold,
        uint256 initialQuorum
    )
        CoreRef(_core)
        Governor("ECG Governor")
        GovernorVotes(IVotes(_token))
        //@audit follow-up weird that it is using OZ library instead of GuildTImelockController.sol (Why is it payable)
        GovernorTimelockControl(TimelockController(payable(_timelock)))
        GovernorSettings(
            initialVotingDelay,
            initialVotingPeriod,
            initialProposalThreshold
        )
    {
        _setQuorum(initialQuorum);
    }
```